# GWT- FormPanel response null on submitcompletehandler

Tags: java, asp.net, gwt, response, formpanel

We have a form panel in gwt.

The action of our form panel is set to an aspx page.
As per the expected output, the info sent through form panel using `POST` method, is set into the action aspx page and after the successful response we will be redirected to the action aspx page.

But we receive null from `getResults()` function of `onSubmitCompleteHandler`.
when we check response value of request Network section of inspect element we found the same result as expected.

Comment: Is the request sent to the same origin? BTW, I'd suggest using [`FormData`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) whenever possible (yes, that means using JSNI) for better control of responses.

Comment: no the request sent to the different origin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the results if you post the form cross-origin.

From the javadoc:

> **Tip:**
>       The result html can be `null` as a result of submitting a form to a different domain.

– Source: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent.html#getResults()

Comment: so how to get result from different domain but when we are preform same process through Dot.Net we reach to perfect result.